# Country selection for Ruby on Rails web form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to include country selection select box in my Rails web form. How is it possible in Ruby on Rails? My form is like this

```
<%= form_for :User, :url => {:action => :create } do |f| %>              
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :select_countries %><br />
    <%= f.select(:countries, country_list)  %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

What can I include in place of country_list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= f.country_select :country, ["United States"] %>
```

It really works for country_select gem

Comment: [i18n country select](https://github.com/onomojo/i18n_country_select) allows you to do the same thing but using standard two-letter codes instead of concrete English words for countries: this example has a field "country" that contains the code, and the selection box adds a preferred country field at the top, saying "Sweden" in localized form. The key for Sweden is "SE". `= f.country_code_select(:country, [[ I18n.t(:SE, :scope => :countries), 'SE' ]])`

Answer (score 4):

My opinion is to seed the countries list in database.

Create a model country with field 'name'.

In app/models/country.rb

```
attr_accessible :name
```

Load the list of country from the YAML file and seed into the database.

In config/country.yml

```
-
 name: India
 name: Pakistan
 name: Cuba
 #add required country name
```

In db/seed.rb

```
COUNTRIES  = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config/country.yml'))
COUNTRIES.each do |country|
  Country.create(country)
end
```

Run

```
rake db:seed
```

Add country_id field in your user model(Write a migration to add field).

In app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 #associate user with country
 belongs_to :country
end
```

In your new user form add the below code.

```
 <%= f.select :country_id, Country.all.collect { |country| [country.name, country.id] },
  { :prompt => "Select Country" } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails used to provide a country select feature in the past. The feature has been extracted out from core and it's now packaged into the [country_select](https://github.com/chrislerum/country_select) plugin.

Use the plugin to enable the feature.